# Create new file using heredoc in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, heredoc

I'm sorry if anyone has already asked the question, I searched for it and have not yet found an answer.
I need to create a new text file using heredoc by only one command line.
What I have tried so far without success, something like this-

```
cat << "" >> newfile.txt
```

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "only one command line"? In a single command on single line, or in a single command that may span multiple lines?

Comment: [How can I write a heredoc to a file in Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2953081/608639), [Open and write data to text file using Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11162406/608639), [Echo a large chunk of text to a file using Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6896025/608639), etc.

Comment: Can you not just `touch` a file?

Answer (score 2):

Triple quotes denote a herestring:

```
# append blank line, create if it doesn't exist
cat <<< "" >> newfile.txt
```

There's no reason to use the herestring. A simpler way to do it would be:

```
# append blank line, create if it doesn't exist
echo >> newfile.txt
```

You realize both of those are appending a blank line to the file? If you're just trying to create a completely empty file with size 0, do this instead:

```
# create empty file, truncate if it already exists
> newfile.txt
```

That will truncate the file if it already exists. If you just want to ensure a file exists but leave it alone if it already does:

```
# create empty file, do nothing if it already exists
touch newfile.txt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm sorry if I was not clear. I want to create a text file using heredoc (<<).
I know the ways you offer but I need to do that with heredoc in on command.